# Maze not being random

Tags: python, backtracking, depth-first-search, maze

Hey there, I am building a program that generates a maze so I can later translate the path to my graphical part. I have most of it working, however, every time you can just take the east and south routes, and you'll get to the end. Even if I set the width as high as 64, so the maze is 64*64, I'm able to choose those 2 options and get to the end every time. I really don't understand why it is doing that. The code is below, it's fairly easy to understand.

```
import random

width = 8

def check(x,y):
    """Figures out the directions that Gen can move while"""
    if x-1 == -1:
        maze[x][y][3] = 0 

    if x+1 == width + 1:
        maze[x][y][1] = 0

    if y+1 == width + 1:
        maze[x][y][2] = 0

    if y-1 == -1:
        maze[x][y][0] = 0

    if x + 1 in range(0,width) and visited[x+1][y] == False:
        maze[x][y][1] = 2

    if x - 1 in range(0,width) and visited[x-1][y] == False:
        maze[x][y][3] = 2

    if y + 1 in range(0,width) and visited[x][y+1] == False:
        maze[x][y][2] = 2

    if y - 1 in range(0,width) and visited[x][y-1] == False:
        maze[x][y][0] = 2

def possibleDirs(x,y):
    """Figures out the ways that the person can move in each square"""
    dirs = []
    walls = maze[x][y]

    if walls[0] == 1:
        dirs.append('n')
    if walls[1] == 1:
        dirs.append('e')
    if walls[2] == 1:
        dirs.append('s')
    if walls[3] == 1:
        dirs.append('w')

    return dirs


def Gen(x,y):
    """Generates the maze using a depth-first search and recursive backtracking."""
    visited[x][y] = True
    dirs = []
    check(x,y)

    if maze[x][y][0] == 2:
        dirs.append(0)
    if maze[x][y][1] == 2:
        dirs.append(1)
    if maze[x][y][2] == 2:
        dirs.append(2)
    if maze[x][y][3] == 2:
        dirs.append(3)
    print dirs

    if len(dirs):
        #Randonly selects a derection for the current square to move
        past.append(current[:])
        pos = random.choice(dirs)

        maze[x][y][pos] = 1  

        if pos == 0:
            current[1] -= 1
            maze[x][y-1][2] = 1
        if pos == 1:
            current[0] += 1
            maze[x+1][y][3] = 1
        if pos == 2:
            current[1] += 1
            maze[x][y+1][0] = 1
        if pos == 3:
            current[0] -= 1
            maze[x-1][y][1] = 1

    else:
        #If there's nowhere to go, go back one square
        lastPlace = past.pop()
        current[0] = lastPlace[0]
        current[1] = lastPlace[1]



#Build the initial values for the maze to be replaced later
maze = []
visited = []
past = []

#Generate empty 2d list with a value for each of the xy coordinates
for i in range(0,width):
    maze.append([])
    for q in range(0, width):
        maze[i].append([])
        for n in range(0, 4):
            maze[i][q].append(4)

#Makes a list of falses for all the non visited places
for x in range(0, width):
    visited.append([])
    for y in range(0, width):
        visited[x].append(False)

dirs = []
print dirs

current = [0,0]

#Generates the maze so every single square has been filled. I'm not sure how this works, as it is possible to only go south and east to get to the final position.
while current != [width-1, width-1]:
    Gen(current[0], current[1])
#Getting the ways the person can move in each square
for i in range(0,width):
    dirs.append([])
    for n in range(0,width):
        dirs[i].append([])
        dirs[i][n] = possibleDirs(i,n)

print dirs
print visited

pos = [0,0]

#The user input part of the maze
while pos != [width - 1, width - 1]:
    dirs = []
    print pos
    if maze[pos[0]][pos[1]][0] == 1:
        dirs.append('n')
    if maze[pos[0]][pos[1]][1] == 1:
        dirs.append('e')
    if maze[pos[0]][pos[1]][2] == 1:
        dirs.append('s')
    if maze[pos[0]][pos[1]][3] == 1:
        dirs.append('w')
    print dirs
    path = raw_input("What direction do you want to go: ")
    if path not in dirs:
        print "You can't go that way!"
        continue
    elif path.lower() == 'n':
        pos[1] -= 1        
    elif path.lower() == 'e':
        pos[0] += 1   
    elif path.lower() == 's':
        pos[1] += 1
    elif path.lower() == 'w':
        pos[0] -= 1

print"Good job!"
```

As you can see, I think the problem is at the point where I generate the maze, however, when I just have it go until the current point is at the end, it doesn't fill every maze and is usually just one straight path. Thanks for helping.

Update:
I have changed the for loop that generates the maze to a simple while loop and it seems to work much better. It seems that when the for loop ran, it didn't go recursively, however, in the while loop it's perfectly fine. However, now all the squares do not fill out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an iterative approach, not a recursive one like your code states!

Check out this series of great articles on maze generation (starting with recursive backtracking):

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/27/maze-generation-recursive-backtracking

Comment: Is there a way to make it recursive in its current state? Or would it require a huge code rewrite. If so, is there an easy way to fix the iterative process to work.

Comment: Hmm, I'd rewrite it following that guide (or other material you find, there's plenty :) if I were you. The code above is kinda messy.

Comment: Are there any changes that I can make without rewriting it entirely? I've done a lot of work on it and wouldn't want to see all of it go to waste.

Comment: I don't see how rewriting it is wasting! Few things let you learn MORE than coding, identifying problems with an approach and trying another one. Also, come on, the code is a page and a half long :). If you want reasons to rewrite: try to make it object-oriented; use python built-in syntax instead of equivalent methods when it looks better; avoid magic numbers, mysterious additions or substractions, use functions and named "constants"(python) instead; avoid long series of conditional statements that practically don't alter the flow of the program, use `elif` if they are exclusive. Length limit

Comment: Wait, I just reread the article, and it seems like I have done this in my code. The article says to start at a point(0,0) and then randomly select a wall to go through, and do that until you get to a dead end. Than you backup, and repeat the whole process. Isn't this what I'm doing in my Gen function? If I added another value to the position as True or False, and then when it has been backtracked to, make that value True, than when the starting point is True, end the function, wouldn't that work?(Run on much?) If I removed the for loop on the Gen function, this seems like it would work.

Comment: Now, figure out how that changed your generator from working iteratively to working recursively. And read that link.

Comment: I read the link for a third time and I think I finally understand it after some movie editing, I don't know why, but it just clicked when I was doing that. The reason it's working correctly now is because it does not force the program to work on every single space, it only does its work on the ones that the program has moved the cursor to. Therefore, when it reaches its goal, it ends. When I was using it on every block, I wasn't allowing it to play out until the end of the path, which made the path go straight down as it was not really randomly working, actually just going through every block.

Comment: Congratulations. Those "it just clicked!" moments are one of the things that make programming worthwhile.

Comment: Congratulations from me too! "Clicking" rules.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an iterative maze generator, not a recursive backtracker maze generator. Gen isn't recursive in its current form; it's iterative. You're calling it once for every tile; if you check in the step-through, the problem should be evident.